.NET 8 Blazor Server - role authorization with Windows Authentication
I have a solution in .NET 7 that works ok, however I want to migrate to .NET 8 with new structure that MS presented and I am facing a lot of issues as authentication does not work the way I would like to.
So in AuthService I have a logic to get data from AD. I get there First name, Last Name, Email, Department based on the username I get in CustomServerAuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync. With this approach I get SSO.
If user has not been on site yet I register him and create a record in database where I am later on able to assign him a proper roles that he needs for his work. If his username is already found in database then I just read his roles and assing them to ClaimsIdentity -> userWinIdentity.AddClaims(_userService.GetRolesClaims());
So I migrated everyting to new .NET8 solution and it works if I come to the page with clicking to link from main menu that navigates user to Profile.razor page. When I am there and press F5 to refresh the page then I get this error:
Access to host localhost is denied.
You do not have user rights to view this page.
HTTP 403 ERROR

Program.cs
using BlazorServer.Data;
using BlazorServer.Providers;
using BlazorServer.Services;
using BlazorServer.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MudBlazor.Services;
using BlazorServer.Consts;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddLocalization();
builder.Services.AddMudServices();

builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<RoleService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<TimeZoneService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomServerAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.MapControllers();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
        .SetDefaultCulture(CultureConsts.supportedCultures[0])
        .AddSupportedCultures(CultureConsts.supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(CultureConsts.supportedCultures);

app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

app.Run();


CustomServerAuthenticationStateProvider.cs
public class CustomServerAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider, IHostEnvironmentAuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly AuthService _authService;
    private readonly UserService _userService;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private Task<AuthenticationState> _authenticationStateTask;

    public CustomServerAuthenticationStateProvider(AuthService authService, UserService userService, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _authService = authService;
        _userService = userService;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        var userWinIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)httpContext?.User.Identity!;

        if (userWinIdentity != null && userWinIdentity.IsAuthenticated && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userWinIdentity.Name))
        {
            var username = userWinIdentity.Name.Split('\\').Last();
            User userObj = _authService.Authenticate(username);
            _userService.User = userObj;

            userWinIdentity.AddClaims(_userService.AddCustomUserClaims());
            userWinIdentity.AddClaims(_userService.GetRolesClaims());
        }

        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(userWinIdentity);
        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
    }

    public void SetAuthenticationState(Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask)
    {
        _authenticationStateTask = authenticationStateTask ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(authenticationStateTask));
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(_authenticationStateTask);
    }
}

UserService.cs
public List<Claim> AddCustomUserClaims()
{
    return
    [
        new Claim("FullName", User.FullName)
    ];
}

public List<Claim> GetRolesClaims()
{
    List<Claim> claims = new();

    foreach (var role in User.Roles)
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GroupSid, role.Name));
// if I use ClaimTypes.Role then it does not work properly on Profile.razor, I do not know why. If someone has a clue please let me know
    
    return claims;
}

Profile.razor
@page "/profile"
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = $"{SecurityGroup.RegisteredUser}")]
@inject UserService userService
@rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>@localizer["Info portal"] | @localizer["Profile"]</PageTitle>

<AuthorizeView>
    @if (user != null)
    {
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" style="font-weight: bold;">
                    @localizer["Username"]
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                    @user.Username
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" style="font-weight: bold;">
                    @localizer["First name"]
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                    @user.FirstName
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" style="font-weight: bold;">
                    @localizer["Last name"]
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                    @user.LastName
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" style="font-weight: bold;">
                    @localizer["Email"]
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                    @user.Email
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" style="font-weight: bold;">
                    @localizer["Department"]
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                    @user.Department
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    }
</AuthorizeView>


@code {
    User user = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        user = userService.User;
    }

}


User.cs
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Department { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string PersonalNr { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

}

I set following properties to be able to get user that is logged in windows acount:
Double click on project:
  <PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
**<UseWindowsService>true</UseWindowsService>**

Right click on project -> properties -> debug -> open debug launch profiles -> Enable Windows Authentication
The issue is that CustomServerAuthenticationStateProvider is not triggered on page refresh.
I was checking already everywhere and checking a lot of different approaches but none of them work, so I can't figure out what I need to do to solve that.
There is also one mistery that I do not know the answer.
In UserService I have a method to add claims based on roles that user has defined in database.
If I add them like that: claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GroupSid, role.Name)); then authorization works in production.
If I fake a login on my development machine like that:
userWinIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "username"),
}, "Fake authentication type");

then I need to update the code in UserService and use it like that claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
This is like that in .NET 7. If anyone knows why it behaves differently in development and production please let me know.
So any help would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT:
I was playing arround and I figure out that from what I get from template I changed Routes.razor, basically I added  even though it should not be needed. If I remove that piece of code then my code does not even work.
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>

In that case I get that error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
InfoPortal.Components.Layout.UserButton.<BuildRenderTree>b__0_5(RenderTreeBuilder __builder2)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
InfoPortal.Components.Layout.UserButton.<BuildRenderTree>b__0_5(RenderTreeBuilder __builder2)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.AddContent(int sequence, RenderFragment fragment)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<.ctor>b__6_0(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, out Exception renderFragmentException)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.HandleExceptionViaErrorBoundary(Exception error, ComponentState errorSourceOrNull)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessPendingRender()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(int componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderHandle.Render(RenderFragment renderFragment)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.HandleExceptionViaErrorBoundary(Exception error, ComponentState errorSourceOrNull)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToPendingTasksWithErrorHandling(Task task, ComponentState owningComponentState)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SupplyCombinedParameters(ParameterView directAndCascadingParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(int componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HtmlRendering.Infrastructure.StaticHtmlRenderer.BeginRenderingComponent(IComponent component, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.EndpointHtmlRenderer.RenderEndpointComponent(HttpContext httpContext, Type rootComponentType, ParameterView parameters, bool waitForQuiescence)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.RazorComponentEndpointInvoker.RenderComponentCore(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.RazorComponentEndpointInvoker.RenderComponentCore(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext+<>c+<<InvokeAsync>b__10_0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

EDIT 2:
Sample project https://easyupload.io/5oejk7

It needs the configuration of your production environment to check the reason of the different behavior of your claims. The error message is clear that some object has not got an instance, which means you need to check whether some service is not registered correctly or some objects lack the instance. I cannot reproduce the issue locally as some code lacks, it will be better if you could provide a minimal reproducible code sample.

@FengzhiZhou
I added link to sample project to first post. Thanks for having a look.

@FengzhiZhou You only need to create migration file. I was using existing db so I forgot to add it.

I managed to solve the issue with one of the solution adviced on that link.
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5362704/Blazor-windows-authentication-with-custom-claims
The solution that I used is:
program.cs needs to point to a custom authenticator with a custom scheme->
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "CustomWindowsAuthentication";
}).AddScheme<CustomWindowsAuthenticationOptions, CustomWindowsAuthenticationHandler>("CustomWindowsAuthentication", null);

Then you do indeed need an additional class that handles that stuff:
public class CustomWindowsAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomWindowsAuthenticationOptions>
{
    public CustomWindowsAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<CustomWindowsAuthenticationOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (!Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !(Context.User.Identity is WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity))
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
        }

        var loginName = windowsIdentity.Name;
        if (loginName.Contains("User1")
            || loginName.Contains("User2")
            || loginName.Contains("User3")
            || loginName.Contains("User4"))
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("CustomClaim", "Admin")
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }

        return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Custom authentication failed.");
    }
}

And for the sake of completeness the "CustomWindowsAuthenticationOptions" because you need that too, although it's empty since i don't need any super special options.
public class CustomWindowsAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    
}

